# Display partial view in a main View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Please I need to know how to display a partial view in a specific area in the main view , this is my source code 
Main View: cshtml

```
<table  align="left" border="5px" cellspacing="2px" style="border:2px solid black">
<tr>       
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="border:2px solid black">
                <div style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc; height: 700px; width: 500px; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;" align="center">Select Baseline Image
                    <input type="button" value="Upload" align="right">
                    <div style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc; height: 500px; width: 300px; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;" align="center">@Html.Partial("_DisplayImage")</div>
                    </div>
                <form method="POST">
                    <input id="leftUrlTB" name="URL" type="Text" style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc"/>
                    <input id="leftBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Firefox" type="radio" />Firefox<br>
                    <input id="leftBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Chrome" type="radio" />Chrome<br>
                    <input id="leftBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Internet Explorer" type="radio" />Internet Explorer<br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Capture" align="right">
                </form>
            </td>                

            <td style="border:2px solid black">
                <div style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc; height: 700px; width: 500px; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;" align="center">Select Comparison Image
                    <input type="button" value="Upload" align="right">
                    <div style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc; height: 500px; width: 300px; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;" align="center"></div></div>

                <form method="POST">
                    <input id="rightUrlTB" name="URL" type="Text" style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc"/>
                    <input id="rightBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Firefox" type="radio" />Firefox<br>
                    <input id="rightBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Chrome" type="radio" />Chrome<br>
                    <input id="rightBrowser" name="leftBrowser" value="Internet Explorer" type="radio" />Internet Explorer<br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Capture" align="right">
                </form>

            </td>
        </tr>    

    </table>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td  >
        <div style="background-color: #fff; border: 6px solid #ccc; height: 700px; width: 1100px; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;" align="center"></div>
    </td>
```

the partial view code is this one :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("WebAppView")" />
```

And I got those controllers :

```
public ActionResult WebAppView()
    {
        return View();
    }

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WebAppView(string url, string selectedBrowserRadio)
    {
      selectedBrowserRadio = Request.Form["leftBrowser"];
      selectedBrowserRadio = selectedBrowserRadio.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
      var selectedBrowser = (Browser)Enum.Parse(typeof(Browser), selectedBrowserRadio, true);
      var bmp= ScreenShotter.TakeScreenShot(selectedBrowser, url);
      var converter = new ImageConverter();
      var bmpArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmp, typeof(byte[]));
      return File(bmpArray,"image/png");
    }


  public ViewResult _DisplayImage()
  {
      return View("_DisplayImage");
  }
```

My problem is that the image returned is displayed in the whole view not in the div area in which I specified. I need to render it in the left div area 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
  public ActionResult WebAppView()
  {
     return View();
  }
```

into

```
public ActionResult WebAppView()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working, it has the same result that I got before, w whole view displaying the image, not displaying it in the left area of the table

Comment: Try what @KevDevMan said, maybe your problem is with the _DisplaImage and not the <img src="@Url.Action("WebAppView")" />.

If still not solving your problem, can I ask what is the post method of WebAppView used for?
<img src="@Url.Action("WebAppView")" /> will only access the get version, but not post version.
hence maybe you are expecting the post method to fire (by the look you hoping getting a file), but instead you got a html view from get

Comment: in fact what I wanted to do is to take a screen shot as a Bitmap object of a giving webpage, so the Http post method is going to return a file to me and I'm going to use this file in the <img src = ...>, and after that I have to display this image  in a specific area in the main view

Comment: Try put this in your _DisplayImage
@{
Layout = null;
}

see if it helps

Comment: maybe the problem is from WebAppView() view, can you show the view code for that action?

Comment: I posted all the code that I got, the WebAppView() view is what I called the main view

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Partial("_DisplayImage") should call directly to the partial view and not go through the controller.

Did you mean to use @Html.RenderAction() to call the Action method? and if so your action method is returning a view("_DisplayImage") result and not a PartialView("_DisplayImage") which it should be.

Comment: sorry how is that? how the @Html.Partial("_DisplayImage") can call directly to the partial view and not go through the controller.? 
I'm pretty new to Asp.net mvc

Comment: Thats what Partial does, look at its argument list 'stringPartialViewName'. RenderAction() will take controller and Action arguments